# What is the -I f lag in protoc tool for Protocol Buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers

The `-I` flag in protoc cli is not documented i.e. `protoc --help` does not list it in `libprotoc 3.13.0`

```
protoc -I src/ --go_out=src/ src/proto/greet/greetpb/greet.proto
```

Yet I see many people use it.
Can someone explain the -I flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto

> The `protocol compiler` searches for imported files in a set of directories specified on the protocol compiler command line using the `-I`/--proto_path flag. If no flag was given, it looks in the directory in which the compiler was invoked. In general you should set the --proto_path flag to the root of your project and use fully qualified names for all imports.

Clunky code-style highlights by me.

That `protocol compiler` is of course the `protoc` tool.

So, it seems it's an alias for `proto_path`, a kind of search-directory, like all compilers tend to have, for looking up imported files. Think C++ and #include lookup paths, Java and classpath, and so on.

Comment: i.e. it specifies where to look for imports if imports are provided, got it, thank you.